# Javascript: how to select text with touch and prevent dragging of screen

Tags: javascript, touch, selection

[image]

On desktop i have mousedown and mouseup, and when i have mouseup, i also use windows.GetSelection() - no problems here!

But in order to do the same on mobile, i have to work with the four touchevents:

```
touchstart, touchend, touchmove, touchcancel
```

and i have to prevent the touchscreen from dragging - propably using `e.preventDefault` but how would the code look?

excerpt from code:

```
$("body").on("mousedown touchstart", ".redbox", async function (e) { [...] });

$("body").on("mouseup touchend","p.redbox", function(e) {

    this.addEventListener("mouseleave", () => {
        document.removeEventListener("selectionchange", logSelection);          
    })
   
    
    });
      if (this.innerHTML != "") {
        selectTextFromWindow(e);
    }
    
});

function selectTextFromWindow(event) {
    
    var selectionObject = window.getSelection();

    [...]      

    }       

}
```